# Android draw() is not being called when new keyword is used to instantiate an object of customview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view, ondraw

I have a custom view with a corresponding custom layout xml which I want to display in a list view (so I can have multiple of these in a list).

As a test I did this in onCreate():

```
cstmView s = findViewById(R.id.card);
s.setImg(R.drawable.ac);
```

with:

```
<views.cstmView
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

So I know that the view is being initialized and drawn from `cstmView.java`

However, I want to create a list view so I can have multiple `cstmView` in a scrollable list. This is what I did ( as a test I just put one cstmView in the list view):

```
Listv = new ArrayList<>();
//adding just one cstmview
Listv.add(new cstmView(this.getApplicationContext()));
//this is my custom adapter to accept cstm layour rathern than a textview
cstmAdapter adapter = new cstmAdapter(this, R.layout.cstm_view, ListV);
ListView cstmListView = findViewById(R.id.cstmListView);
cstmListView(adapter);
```

Although this is putting the cstmView in list, it is not running the overridden `draw` function in `cstmView`.

I think the problem is with `new cstmView(this.getApplicationContext())` because the same problem arises with or without the list view. does the `new` keyword not run `draw()` ?

this is the method that should be calling draw in cstmView.java

```
public void init(Context context){
    System.out.println("INIT");
    // To instantiate an XML layout file from the already configured R.layout
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cstm_view, this);

    // Get elements in layout

    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    back = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    // to convert
    cornerRadius = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, CORNER_RADIUS, metrics);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    maskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);
    maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    // to draw the above
    setWillNotDraw(false);

}
```

and then the on draw function creates some bitmaps and so on...

```
 @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("DRAW");
    // create a bitmap with this context height and width
    Bitmap offscreenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas offscreenCanvas = new Canvas(offscreenBitmap);

    super.draw(offscreenCanvas);

    if (maskBitmap == null) {
        maskBitmap = createMask(getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    offscreenCanvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, 0f, 0f, maskPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(offscreenBitmap, 0f, 0f, paint);


}

private Bitmap createMask(int width, int height) {

    System.out.println("CREATE MASK");
    Bitmap mask = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mask);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, width, height), cornerRadius, cornerRadius, paint);

    return mask;
}
```

## update

calling `invalidate()` in constructor solves the problem. However, I still am not seeing the renders on-screen that `draw` is supposedly doing. Is there something wrong with the `arrayAdatper`? :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View rowView = convertView;
        //if data already exists in list reuse the data rather than re inflate from scratch
        if(rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
        }
        return rowView;
    }
```

Comment: also post draw method code here

Comment: @PrachiSingh just update the code with the draw function.

Comment: I could not understand your purpose. If you share what you want to do, I can help.

Answer (score 1):

call method `invalidate()` it will call **onDraw()** implicitly

Comment: where should I call it? in init() or after the new keyword in onCreate()?

Comment: in cstView's constructor

Comment: although this does call draw() it is not displaying the rounded corners and other renders implemented in draw. is it because in arrayAdapter I am calling `rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);`? I updated the question